# Installing laravel and composer on Debian 6

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to use laravel, so, firstly I have to install composer, I uploaded laravel in a folder "laravel" now i go to the folder and I do this

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

according the site of composer...

So, now, according laravel I should do this

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

but returns **"composer command not found"**

When I finished installing composer I get this **Use it: php composer.phar**

So, I try again `php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel`

and it runs,but it stays as **Installing dependencies (incluiding require-dev)** for a long long time.

My enviroment is Debian 6, and its a cloud server, so, internet should not be a problem.
It just stays like that, any idea what I'm doing wrong? How to solve this and make it run?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
# if you're installing as root or privileged account, don't leave the permissions on default 777
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
$ composer install
```